# Big ask: could anyone give me a tutorial to compile entangle 0.6.0?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy

I have tried following their instructions, and I always seem to get errors. Other tutorials refer to old versions of things. I am running wheezy raspian.

http://entangle-photo.org/compiling/

Answer (score 1):

Note, instead of just doing all the compiling, you would likely be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install entangle
```

You may be able to download the relevant deb package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/entangle) if not - the [i386 package](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/entangle/entangle_0.6.0-1_i386.deb) might work...

---

**To compile it**

Basically you just need to use the instructions for Debian, and when it says run as root prefix the command with `sudo` - alot of the provided instructions look like they have just been made up... - These commands should work:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool libltdl-dev zlib1g-dev libusb-dev  libgpmg1-dev pkg-config libexif-dev libjpeg-dev doxygen graphviz libdbus-1-dev libgd2-xpm-dev wget
cd $HOME
wget http://entangle-photo.org/download/sources/entangle-0.6.0.tar.gz
mkdir build
cd build
tar xvf ../entangle-0.6.0.tar.gz
cd entangle-0.6.0/
./configure --prefix=$HOME/build/entangle-0.6.0
make
make install
```

I haven't tested them yet - the last command (`make install`) may need to be run as root (`sudo make install`).

If any errors about missing packages occur whilst running `./configure`, search for the missing package with `sudo apt-cache search PACKAGENAME`, then install any relevant matches with `sudo apt-get install PACKAGES`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I will try this today and report back :)

Comment: *Update* After installing all the missing packages, I know have an error during `make`. Couldn't find include GExiv2-0.4.gir

Comment: Searching for it, as far as I can see it is almost definitely in a version of the package `libgexiv2-dev` - which version though is a bit of an issue. [This](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/ubuntu-main-i386/libgexiv2-dev_0.4.90-0ubuntu1_i386.deb.html) package seems to have the right version, even though it is for Ubuntu (should install fine anyway)

Comment: Interesting , thanks for looking. Would it best to remove / purge the existing package?

Comment: dunno, which version is it? - googling it i could find versions with `GExiv2-0.10.gir`, and versions without it at all... i believe the technical term for this is [`Dependency Hell`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) - though this probably has not reached that stage yet :-)

Comment: I have `libgexiv2-dev 0.4.1-3`

Comment: The package you have suggested will not install as it "doesn't match the system (armhf)

Comment: [This one](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/libgexiv2-dev/filelist) has version GExiv2-0.10.gir, the [version for wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armhf/libgexiv2-dev/filelist) doesn't seem to have it at all... So installing [the first version](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/libgexiv2-dev/filelist) then running `sudo ln -s /usr/share/gir-1.0/GExiv2-0.10.gir /usr/share/gir-1.0/GExiv2-0.4.gir` (creates a link from one file to the other) might work as it fulfills the dependency, but may have issues with it being the wrong version.

Comment: Gah. `Preparing to replace libgexiv2-dev 0.4.1-3 (using libgexiv2-dev_0.10.1-1_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgexiv2-dev ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgexiv2-dev:
 libgexiv2-dev depends on libgexiv2-2 (= 0.10.1-1); however:
  Package libgexiv2-2 is not installed.
 libgexiv2-dev depends on gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10 (= 0.10.1-1); however:
  Package gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10 is not installed.`

Comment: Install `gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10`, or add it to the install command - `apt` is *useless*....

Comment: I think I am doing this wrong..
 `sudo dpkg -i libgexiv2-dev_0.10.1-1_armhf.deb gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10_0.10.1-1_armhf.deb... dependency problems prevent configuration of libgexiv2-dev: libgexiv2-dev depends on libgexiv2-2 (= 0.10.1-1); however:  Package libgexiv2-2 is not installed.dpkg: error processing libgexiv2-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10: gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10 depends on libgexiv2-2 (>= 0.9.1);`

Answer (score 1):

About "GExiv2-0.4.gir" error, please check this link. It may help you
http://kahverengi.com/EN/article/linux/entangle-0-6-0-install-error.html

> When you try to install entangle 0.6.0, you may face an error like
>
> "Couldn't find include GExiv2-0.4.gir"
>
> Solution:
>
> You need to reinstall the gexiv2 as described here
>
> https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2/BuildingAndInstalling
>
> Note that the configuraion option --enable-introspection.
>
> With that option "GExiv2-0.4.gir" file is installed into the correct path and after that you can install entagle without problem.